# SQL one to many , many to many, query Build

Tags: sql, many-to-many, one-to-many, pivot-table

basically in order to process things quickly I need to be able to access the info from two tables linked by an intermediate reached by a one to many and then a many to many relationship. Specifically I have, the following relevant tables

users[id, ...]

trips[user_id,...]

trip_type[id,trip_id,type_id]

types[id,...]

i.e Users have many trips which have many types which themselves have many trips.

My aim is to get a list of every type id (with repetitions should they occur) associated with a particular user via every trip they have taken.

I'm sure this is trivial to the SQL inclined but I am not one of those individuals and as such am just writing nonsense at this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
select users.id, trip_type.type_id, count(*) from users join trips on trips.user_id = users.id join trip_type on trips.id = trip_type.trip_id group by users.id, trip_type.type_id
```

This will also give you a count of how many trips of each type a user has taken. This query will not list users who have not taken any trips. If you need those users as well change the word 'join' to 'left join'

Comment: Is this definitely correct, there is no trips.type_id? (myPHPadmin doesn't like it either)

Comment: No, sorry missed a table, i have edited the answer, try that and let me know. It still may not be 100% as i don't have a database with that structure to test.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tt.type_id, u.user_id, tr.id
FROM trip_type tt
 INNER JOIN trips tr ON tr.id = tt.trip_id
 INNER JOIN types ty ON ty.id = tt.type_id
 INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = tr.user_id
 WHERE u.user_id = ?
```

This will return type_ids, user_id and trip ids for a particular user.